# Operator "!" cannot be applied to operando of type Task<bool>

Tags: c#

I have the following method from a library:

```
IRuleBuilderOptions<T1, T2> MustAsync<T1, T2>(this IRuleBuilder<T1, T2> ruleBuilder, Func<T2, CancellationToken, Task<bool>> predicate);
```

And I use it as follows:

```
.MustAsync((t2, token) => someAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskBoolean());
```

But I am not able to negate the method as so:

```
.MustAsync((t2, token) => !someAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskBoolean());
```

Because I get the error:

```
Operator "!" cannot be applied to operand of type Task<bool>
```

I cannot change the method because it is from an external library.

How can I solve this?

Comment: ^ seems like the same problem - `async`... Also, do you mean "operands"?

Comment: In this case the answers in "Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Task' and 'int' " do not solve the problem

Comment: Use `async` lambda and `await`, e.g. `.MustAsync(async (t2, token) => !await someAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskBoolean());`

Comment: @IvanStoev that is the answer. Can you add it so I can mark it?

Comment: I can't because the question is closed as duplicate. Nevermind, problem solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
async (t2, token) => !(await someAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskBoolean())
```

This will complete the task and apply your ! to the result (ie. the boolean) rather than the task itself.

Comment: should remove the .Result answer....since that's just an awesome way to destroy asyncness

Comment: With your suggestion I get the error "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier

Comment: And Result is just converting Task<Bool> to bool which removes async behavior

Comment: Yes, the ! will always be applied after the function completes, so applying it here will require you not to have async behavior. I recommend adding the ! when you get the result of the function, though I can't peg exactly where that is without seeing more of your code. Basically, when you put that boolean to use, THEN apply the !.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Use `.MustAsync( async (t2, token) => !(await someAsyncMethodThatReturnsTaskBoolean()));`